# JS Regex - validate specific numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm new to regex and still getting to grpis with it.

I have a list of numbers lets just say this is it :

806
807
808
810
812
813
814
815
816
817
818
819
828
830
831
832
843

I want to incorporate them into a regex for Js thats a max of three characters.

How do I go about this? Is my only option something like this [832,843] or can I incorporate an array?

Comment: what is the final goal?

Comment: Whats the final goal of a regular expresion? Er to validate a certain input field to only allow these specific values.

Comment: input field will be entered with only one of those values? Can the input be `807 122 815` ?

Comment: yes thats right

Comment: show some valid and invalid examples

Comment: It should be a range?

Comment: Hi @VitaliyVinnychenko yes its a range

Comment: /^[0-8]{3,3}$/  will test that the input contains 3 numbers between 0 and 8. Is that what you were trying to achieve?

Comment: @LeoFarmer No it needs to be in this specific range

Comment: are you accepting any numbers between 806 and 843 @dim

Comment: Ask a question break some brains lol

Answer (score 0):

if you need regex to validate numbers in 806 to 843 range:

```
^8(0[6-9]|[1-3]\d|4[0-3])$
```